# SWF : how to avoid reloading when container hides?

Tags: html, flash

I have a swf inside a div.

I apply some animtion to that div like:

```
$('#pushToTalkWindow').slideDown(500);
```

WHen I apply then 
 `$('#pushToTalkWindow').slideUp(500);`

The SWF reloads completly: is there a way to avoid reloading SWF when its container is hides ?

Answer (score 0):

This is browser-specific. Some browsers will completely reload the SWF after it has been hidden, others will leave it as-is. To my knowledge, there is no universal workaround.